# Can a client continue to communicate with an XMPP server after sending the unavailable presence?

Tags: xmpp, user-presence

After the client has sent the server and unavailable presence, can it continue to send the server more XML stanzas for it to process, or should the server ignore these XML stanzas? I couldn't find anything relevant in RFC-3921, but then again I've only skimmed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can continue to send protocol after sending an unavailable presence.  For example, you could go back online, you could send IQs to your server (which should continue to route the replies back to you), and you can send confusing messages to others (confusing because they don't have presence from you).  Just because you can doesn't mean you SHOULD, though.  If you're trying to control the inbound flow of information, consider using [XEP-0273: SIFT](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0273.html) instead.

Comment: So, do you think this is a valid way to become invisible?

Comment: Going offline isn't a valid invisibility approach, since you no longer receive presence updates from your contacts, nor do you receive messages sent to your bare JID.  Please see XEP-0126 for another approach: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0126.html